# why it is not possible to scrape data from this website "https://www.migros.com.tr/" in flutter

Tags: flutter, web-scraping

I tried a lot but was not able to scrape any data from this website. is there any way to scrape data from this website? https://www.migros.com.tr/
I am using HTML and HTTP libraries in flutter.

```
class Scraper {
  static void getData() async {
  
      String URL = "https://www.migros.com.tr/";
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL));
      final body = response.body;
      final html = parse(body);
      
      final names = html.querySelectorAll('.product-name');
    
      final images = html.querySelectorAll('.image >a >img');

      
        print(images[1].atrributes['src'].trim());
print(names[1].text.trim());
       
    
  }
}
```

Comment: @Justinas here you go

Comment: @Tim Roberts can you help

Comment: Running `curl` on that URL shows HTML that basically has an empty body, so there's nothing to scrape.  Anything you observe in your web browser is generated by client-side JavaScript.

Comment: your URL doesn't return JSON make sure it returns JSON data :)

Comment: @ahmedmohamedabdikadir I think it is all because of the website's loading at the first time when you open the website there is a loading. so it think that loading is a barrier

Comment: @ahmedmohamedabdikadir can you please try  and upload the code as answer